# Memory overwrite after allocating 4k ints with new

Tags: c++, memory

After debugging some really weird behaviors, like vectors going from size 0 to negative values out of nowhere, I realized this was happening after allocating 4000 ints with new.
I dont understand, 4k ints (~15KB) is not that huge, and even if it was, why its messing with my mem?
Video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_iN9pcbyoiKQV9lNllLWktfOGc/edit?usp=sharing

In the vid, the structure your seeing is this one:

```
struct TileMap{

    int * pTileMap;
    int mapW, mapH;
    float hSpacing, vSpacing;

    sprite::InstancedSprites m_tileInstSprites;
    sprite::InstancesVertexBuffer m_IVB;

    TileMap():pTileMap(nullptr){}
    ~TileMap(){ if(pTileMap) delete [] pTileMap; }
};
std::vector<TileMap> m_vTileMaps;
```

EDIT

So, even commenting out the allocation, the same thing occurs a few steps later, I will assume is some overwrite at a previous moment?
Any tips on how to debug this?

EDIT 2

The problem has notting to do with the pointer, heres where the thing blows:

```
 sprite::InstancedSprites::InstancedSprites()
:
 m_drawCall(6),
 m_drawCall_warpException(6)
 {
      m_drawable.AddPipelineState( &m_pipeState );
      m_drawable.SetDrawCall( &m_drawCall );

      m_drawable_warpException.AddPipelineState( &m_pipeState );
      m_drawable_warpException.SetDrawCall( &m_drawCall_warpException );
 }
```

Thats the ctor, I believed it should be doing its job just fine, and everything inside drawable is a std::vector (AddPipelineState is adding to a vector).

The way I "solved" it, was by adding the same job the ctor do at this method:

```
    void sprite::InstancedSprites::Initialize( dx::BindPSShaderResourceView &                          pTextureBinder_p, dx::BindOMBlendState & pBlendBinder, dx::BindPSSampler & pSampleState,                      InstancesVertexBuffer & pIVB_p )
    {
      // DBG
      m_drawable.Clear();
      m_drawable.AddPipelineState( &m_pipeState );
      m_drawable.SetDrawCall( &m_drawCall );
      m_drawable_warpException.Clear();
      m_drawable_warpException.AddPipelineState( &m_pipeState );
      m_drawable_warpException.SetDrawCall( &m_drawCall_warpException );

      m_pipeState.Reset();
      m_pipeState.AddBinderCommand( &pTextureBinder_p );
      m_pipeState.AddBinderCommand( &pBlendBinder );
      m_pipeState.AddBinderCommand( &pSampleState );
      m_pipeState.AddBinderCommand( pIVB_p.GetBinder() );
      // missing, IA and camera binds

      m_pIVBref = &pIVB_p;
}
```

The upper part is the fix, I didnt have that (I do had the method), because the ctor already does that...so I really dont get it. If inside drawable it uses vectors, than cant be the rule of three the problem?

EDIT 3

Final solution, a cpy ctor that doesnt copy at all, the thing is, those drawables hold that to data on the owner class, so on a copy, they where getting vectors with data no longer valid...:

```
sprite::InstancedSprites::InstancedSprites( InstancedSprites & /*other_p*/ )
    :
m_drawCall(6),
m_drawCall_warpException(6)
{   

    m_drawable.AddPipelineState( &m_pipeState );
    m_drawable.SetDrawCall( &m_drawCall );

    m_drawable_warpException.AddPipelineState( &m_pipeState );
    m_drawable_warpException.SetDrawCall( &m_drawCall_warpException );
}
```

Comment: Are you actually deallocating that memory somewhere?

Comment: @DjDexter5GHz, no, theres a test before the allocation as you can see in the vid, but it always fails anyway

Comment: Well, allocation problems only appear if you don't deallocate, or write on somebody else's memory. If none of those is true you allocated too much. You seem to delete everything in video, but how about writing in memory that is not yours?

Comment: but the vid shows the exactly moment the overwrite occur, and its just after the allocation

Comment: Well that is the problem with allocation in c++, error occurs on reallocation or sometimes on deletion.

Comment: your right, its not the alloc the problem

Comment: Most likely, some other part of the program has corrupted the heap, but the effect isn't noticed until you perform this allocation.

Comment: using `shared_ptr` instead of `int *` for `pTileMap` should solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::vector<TileMap> m_vTileMaps;
```

You're creating a vector of TileMap objects.  Your TileMap violates *the rule of three*, and any type that violates this rule cannot be used safely in a vector.  In other words, this simple test of your class shows the issues that will occur:

```
int main()
{
  TileMap x;
  // assume x has allocated the ints
  //..
  TileMap y = x;  // trouble, trouble
  TileMap z;
  //.. assume z has allocated ints
  z = x;   // more trouble
}  // double deletion error and memory leak on program exit
```

The above code uses no vector, but shows the types of operations that will be done by vector internally. You see the problems that occur when copies are made.

The vector class will create copies of your TileMap, and your TileMap object is not safely copyable.  You need to add a user-defined copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor (which you provided) to make the class copy correctly.

The other solution is to store a vector of pointers (perferably smart pointer) to a TileMap.

```
std::vector<TileMap*> m_vTileMaps;
m_vTileMaps.reserve(4000);
m_vTileMaps.push_back(new TileMap());
```

Then when releasing the memory:

```
for(auto it=m_vTileMaps.begin(); it!=m_vTileMaps.end(); ++it)
{
    delete(*it);
}
m_vTileMaps.clear();
```

Or by using shared_ptr you could forget that last part.

Another solution is to use vector within your TileMap. You're using vector already, but you refused to use it in where it really counts:

```
struct TileMap
{
    std::vector<int> pTileMap;
    int mapW, mapH;
    float hSpacing, vSpacing;
    sprite::InstancedSprites m_tileInstSprites;
    sprite::InstancesVertexBuffer m_IVB;
};

std::vector<TileMap> m_vTileMaps;  // this is ok now
```

The TileMap class can now be used safely in a vector (I'm assuming that the sprite::* types are safely copyable). You also no longer need to do a delete[] in the destructor.

Comment: problem is still there with the last solution. InstancedSprites and InstancesVertexBuffer both have std::vectors inside (no pointers), and those vectors are the ones getting corrupt as seem in the video. I only managed to get rid of it by using TileMap "sole" (no std::vector<TileMap> m_vTileMaps;).

Comment: Did you change that line that allocates ints to do a vector::resize() instead?  That video at this point is stale *if* you made the changes above.  `m_vTileMaps[it].pTileMap.resize(whatever);`  That is what you should be doing now

Comment: In addition, you can still mess up if you have an out-of-bounds access using vector.  Is the "it" index within bounds of the m_vTileMaps vector?

Comment: Also, don't make coding changes just to make changes.  You need to know exactly why you're making the change.  Right now, it's hard to tell if those changes you said you made really did anything, or possibly masking the real problem.